# Cannot create table due to quota limit

Tags: create-table, quota, azure-synapse

I am trying to create a table in Azure SQL Data Warehouse which has a limit of 10,000 tables.

```
create table dbo.todd (now_ts  datetime);

Error Msg: Msg 105000, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The operation failed due to a quota of no more than 10000 Tables per Database.
```

Executed the below queries to get number of tables:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM [sys].[tables] 

results = 178
```

and

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM [sys].[external_tables]

results = 6
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

This can be caused by a certain pattern of external table creation/deletion. A fix is currently rolling out to prevent this pattern from causing a false positive in table creation.